# Authorizing Google Calendar for Service Account WITHOUT G-Suite

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to use the Google Calendar API with a Service Account to retrieve events. However, listing calendars or events returns nothing (not an error, just 0 records returned). There's lots of documentation/examples for domain-wide authorization using G-Suite, but this just an individual Google account -- it is not part of any G-Suite domain.

I did add the email address of the service account to the calendar under sharing, but the calendar still doesn't show when I try to retrieve data.

Is there a certain URL I should be using? Or is there some kind of configuration setting in Google Console I'm missing?

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer regarding this. Could you please confirm whether that solves your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Service Account's email address is not enough to share the Calendar: the account also has to `accept` the Calendar. Looks like this is because of a recent change of behaviour.

From this [comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148804709#comment2) in Issue Tracker:

> Due to a recent change of behaviour, any account has to explicitly "accept" a Calendar that has been shared with them. In case of a Service Account, this "acceptance" should be made by adding the calendar to the `CalendarList` via [CalendarList.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert).

That is to say, after adding the Service Account address, you have to call [CalendarList.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert) to add this Calendar to the Service Account's calendar list. In your call, you just have to provide the corresponding Calendar `id` in the request body.

#### Reference:

- [#148804709. Service Accounts don't accept automatically shared calendars anymore](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148804709)