# Flutter Google Calendar API - clientViaServiceAccount not responding

Tags: flutter, dart, google-api, google-calendar-api

I know that there are already answers to this question but I couldn't solve my issue looking at them, 
so I hope you will be able to help me or at least suggest me what to try because I am not sure what to do or how to debug in order to solve my issue.

I am trying to list all the events in my company calendar using **Google Calendar Api**.
I used the same code on this **question**: [Using dart and flutter with google calendar api to get a list of events on the a user's calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49414279/using-dart-and-flutter-with-google-calendar-api-to-get-a-list-of-events-on-the-a)

And I followed all the **6 steps** of the **answer** in the question above.

For some reason, the call `clientViaServiceAccount` do not return any result and any errors.
It seems like it is executing an infinity loop.

This is the code I am using, and I can only see printed "getCalendarEvents". I cannot see the msg "HERE" or any error printed. So The issue is for sure in `clientViaServiceAccount`.

I edited the code taking into account [Iamblichus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10612011/iamblichus) suggestion, but the issue is that I cannot even reach the `CalendarApi`. The code is stacked on the `clientViaServiceAccount`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/calendar/v3.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CalendarAPI.getCalendarEvents();
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Container(),
    );
  }
}

class CalendarAPI {
  static final _accountCredentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(r'''
  {
    "private_key_id": myPrivatekeyId,
    "private_key": myPrivateKey,
    "client_email": myClientEmail,
    "client_id": myClientId,
    "type": "service_account"
  }
  ''');
  
  static final _scopes = [CalendarApi.CalendarScope];

  static void getCalendarEvents() {
    print('getCalendarEvents');
    clientViaServiceAccount(_accountCredentials, _scopes).then((client) {
      print('HERE');
      var calendar = new CalendarApi(client);
      print(calendar);

      // Added iamblichus answer
      var calendarListEntry = CalendarListEntry();
      calendarListEntry.id = calendarId;
      calendar.calendarList.insert(calendarListEntry).then((_) {
        print('CALENDAR ADDED');

        var calEvents = calendar.events.list(calendarId);
        calEvents.then((Events events) {
          events.items.forEach((Event event) {
            print(event.summary);
          });
        }).catchError((e) => print(e));
      }).catchError((e) => print(e));
    }).catchError((e) => print(e));
  }
}
```

**EDIT FOR ANSWERING iamblichus COMMENT on Jul 15 at 12:31**

I created the **Service account Credentials** on the page of the image shown below.
As soon as I created the key, I file *.json* was downloaded with the credentials.
I copied the content of that file and paste into **ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson** function, so the credentials cannot be wrong.
And even if the credentials were wrong, why cannot I see an error that `clientViaServiceAccount` call is failing? 
I am catching any error and print them in the screen with the last `}).catchError((e) => print(e));`.
For some reason the call `clientViaServiceAccount` is not doing anything and I cannot understand how to find the reason for that.
[image]

Comment: Not sure if that's what's causing the error you're experiencing, but in order to share a calendar with a Service Account, you need to make an additional step (the SA has to explicitly accept it), as you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62672641). Can you check whether doing this solves your issue?

Comment: Are `myPrivatekeyId`, `myPrivatekey` the actual client data, or they are variable names which you have used to store those? My guess is that you are not providing the correct `_accountCredentials`. In order to troubleshoot this, I'd suggest using `_accountCredentials.toString()` and check if the different credential fields are getting populated correctly.

Comment: My guess was that it was not formatted correctly when you copied the credentials data: `.fromJson(r''' ... ''');`. It's just a guess since I'm not used to this language. Have you tried formatting it as in [the question you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49414279)?: `.fromJson({ ... });`. Do you get the same behaviour?

Comment: btw, apart from editing the question, I'd suggest you to post a new comment in order to make sure this update is seen by others.

Comment: First of all thanks for your help and your tip Iamblichus!
I tried to use the other syntax of `.fromJson` but, unfortunately, the result is the same.

Answer (score 3):

This method works in the cloud. If you want to use it in the flutter app, you have to get the user authenticated using the following plugin,

```
extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth
```